# Overloading a matrix assignment operator, little things that play a big role

Tags: c++, memory, overloading

For example i have this overloaded operator =

```
void operator=(const matrix& a)
{
    if ((this->height != a.height) || (this->lenght != a.lenght))
    {
        if (this->container != nullptr)
        {
            delete this->container;
        }

        this->container = new T[a.height * a.lenght];
        this->lenght = a.lenght;
        this->height = a.height;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < this->height * this->lenght; i++)
    {
        this->container[i] = a.container[i];
    }
}
```

AND this copy constructor

```
matrix(const matrix<T> &a)
{
    this->lenght = a.lenght;
    this->height = a.height;

    this->container = new T[this->lenght * this->height];

    T* adres_A = a.container;
    T* adres_this = this->container;
    for (; adres_this < (this->container + this->lenght * this->height); adres_this++, adres_A++)
        {               
            adres_this[0] = adres_A[0];
        }
}
```

So if i write

```
matrix C = A*B;
```

i use only copy contructor and i can just copy values with my operator= (but it dont used here, its confusing) then i delete matrix that was created by operator* (A*B) (can i use it ? And dont delete?)

but if i write

```
matrix A,B;

A = B;
```

Could a situation arise when I first allocate memory with the copy constructor, and then delete it and allocate it again with the = operator? May be in my copy contructor i must just copy values without allocating memory?

Comment: I recommend that you read [this operator overload canonical implementation reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators#Canonical_implementations), especially about [the assignment operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators#Assignment_operator).

Comment: And unless your assignment or exercise is about manual memory handling please don't do that. Use [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead, and you can follow [the rule of zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three#Rule_of_zero) and simply rely on the compiler-generated assignment operator to do the right thing.

Comment: Regarding "[c]ould a situation arise when I first allocate memory with the copy constructor, and then delete it and allocate it again with the = operator?" Then that's easy  to answer: `matrix C = A; C = B;` Copy-construction followed by copy-assignment. There could still be many statements between them, but it's still a reallocation in the copy-assignment operator.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude That's ill-advised as `std::vector` has a move-constructor, but keeping track of length and height would be necessary when the move operation clears the source in order to keep invariants.

Comment: @j6t A copy-assignment operator with a proper declaration (with a `const` reference to the source) can never move anything. And the `length` and `height` members would be copied as well so nothing is lost.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude But that does not follow the "rule of zero" anymore.

Comment: @j6t By using the compiler-generated copy-constructor and -assignment operator (and remove any destructor) it will. And the compiler-generated variants will have the correct declarations and do the right thing (with a `std::vector`).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude That would do the right thing for the copy and move of the *data*, but not of the `length` and `height` parameters that the class also holds. They would contain incorrect values in the source after a move operation. The source's invariants would certainly be violated when there is no data but non-zero length and height. That should be avoided even in a moved-from object.

Comment: @j6t Once you move from the source, why would you expect its properties to stay the same? You move from an object so you can throw it away (or reinitialize it with new data). What does it matter what those members might be if they're not to be used anymore?